# Perl Template Toolkit <% IF %> conditional seems to not be working

Tags: html, perl, template-toolkit

I have the section of `html` below that I would like to display when the hash 'Season' has value. The trouble is that the section shows up even when Season has no value, I don't even send a variable named Season to the template, or even if I change the line below to `<% IF XSeason.size %>`

```
<% IF Season.size %> <!-- season data -------------------------------------->
<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">
  <div class="row">
    <h3 class="text-center"> This should only show up if Season hash has value</h3>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="form-group">
      <table style="width:100%; line-height:40px;">   <!-- Feats (so far) as a table // -->
        <% FOREACH $name in Seasonkeys %>
        <tr>
          <form role="form" action="../alpview" method="POST">
        <td width="5"><% Season$name.stat %></td> 
        <td width="5"><% Season$name.AVG %></td> 
        <input type="hidden" name="chlng_id" value="<% Season$ID.ID %>" />
          </form>
        </tr>   
        <% END %>   
      </table>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% END %>
```

**UPDATE:** Here is a simpler example.

```
<h2>Lets start with an array reference<h2>
<h3>What about fruits array: </h3>
<% FOREACH fruit IN fruits %>
<% fruit %>
<% END %>
<p>array size: </p><% fruits.size %></p>
<p>array dumped: </p><% USE Dumper; Dumper.dump(fruits) %>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Lets start with an array reference
What about fruits array:
apple bananna orange
array size:

array dumped:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim is easily disproven:

```perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use Template qw( );

my $template = '<% IF Season.size %>Test<% END %>';

my $tt = Template->new({
   START_TAG => '<%',
   END_TAG   => '%>',
});

print "No var:         ";
$tt->process(\$template, { })
   or warn($tt->error());
say "";

print "Empty hash:     ";
$tt->process(\$template, { Season => { } })
   or warn($tt->error());
say "";

print "Not empty hash: ";
$tt->process(\$template, { Season => { a => 4 } })
   or warn($tt->error());
say "";
```

Output:

```
No var:
Empty hash:
Not empty hash: Test
```

Your hash must not be empty.

Comment: No idea what I can be doing wrong. Even if I change <% IF Season.size %> to <% NoWayInTheWorld.size %> it still shows up.

Comment: Sorry, can't tell you what you're doing wrong cause we haven't seen it. That's why you should post a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this just after the `<% IF ... %>` tag.

```
<% Season.size %>
<% USE Dumper; Dumper.dump(Season) %>
```

At least you'll see what TT thinks is in the variable.

Comment: This is a great idea and I thought it would work. But when I put the above code in my page nothing shows up for the hash reference.

Comment: @gatorreina: You realise how that makes no sense, right? :-) The only thing I can suggest is that you provide us with an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can investigate ourselves.

Comment: Dave, I totally realize this makes no sense. I have spent three days going out of my mind trying to get get hash references to appear in Template Toolkit. As for the size argument, I cannot even get that to work for an array. If I do: <p>array size: </p><% fruits.size %></p>
<p>array dumped</p><% USE Dumper; Dumper.dump(fruits) %> for an array reference called fruits and nothing show up --extremely frustrating.

Comment: @gatorreina: As I said, if you create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem, and add it to your question, then someone here will take a look for you. Without a runnable example, we can't do any more.

Comment: @gatorreina: Just as an example, a **minimal** example will, almost certainly, not use HTML :-)

Comment: @gatorreina: One thing that strikes me - you're using `<%` and `%>` as the template tags, but that's not TT's default (that's `[%` and `%]`). Are you using `START_TAG` / `END_TAG` or `TAG_STYLE` when creating your template processor object to change the template tags?

Comment: The style tags are set to <% %> by Dancer. Adding a simple example to my original question.

Comment: Figured it out finally. Dancer uses Template Simple by default and not Template Toolkit. Changing the configuration in config.yml to template Toolkit and enabling TT in my app made everything work.

Comment: @gatorreina: Ah. Well if you'd mentioned that you were using Dancer, we might have had a bit of a clue :-)